# Mongo how to write a CASE WHEN THEN ELSE

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, coalesce

I'm trying to translate to mongo the following sql:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COL_A IS NOT NULL THEN 'aaa' ELSE 'bbb' END AS FLAG, COL_B AS VALUE
FROM MY_TABLE

--- or, at least
SELECT coalesce(COL_A,'bbb') AS FLAG, COL_B AS VALUE
FROM MY_TABLE
```

```
/*sample json data*/
[
 { COL_A: "abc",
   COL_B: "123"
},{
 COL_B: "654"
},
{
COL_A: "zyx",
COL_B: "987"
}

]


/*expected_output*/
{
FLAG: "aaa", /*OR , at least, "abc"*/
VALUE: "123"
},{
FLAG: "bbb", 
VALUE: "654"
},{
FLAG: "aaa", /*or, at least, "zyx"*/
VALUE: "987"
}
```

In mongo I'm Here:

```js
db.getCollection('MyTable').aggregate([    
{
  $project: 
     { 
       "_id": 0, 
       "FLAG" : { 
           $switch :{ 
                      branches: [ 
                                  {case: { "$COL_A": { $exists: true } then: "aaa" } }
                                ],
                       default: "bbb"
                     }
                 }, 

        "VALUE" : "$COL_B"
      }
}, 
{
    $limit:50
}

])
```

But it tells me unexpected identifier

EDIT:

Tested with `$ifNull`: I get an empty array as output instead of expected "bbb"

```js
db.getCollection('MyTable').aggregate([    
{
  $project: 
     { 
       "_id": 0, 
       "FLAG" : {$ifNull: ["$COL_A", "bbb"] },
        "VALUE" : "$COL_B"
      }
}, 
{
    $limit:50
}

])
```

Comment: thanks: but I get_ `"errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$COL_A",
 "code" : 168,"codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"`

Comment: `$exists` is _not_ an aggregation operator. You may have to use the `ifNull` aggregation operator instead.

Comment: how does `$COL_A` look like? is it supposed to be an empty array? do you want to test it against empty array instead of null?

Comment: $COL_A is supposed to be a string but may not be present. I'm adding a couple of BSON records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      "FLAG": {
        $cond: [
          {
            $lte: [
              "$COL_A",
              null
            ]
          },
          "bbb",
          "aaa"
        ]
      },
      "VALUE": "$COL_B"
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 50
  }
])
```

To check if the value doesn't exist or is null use `{ $lte: ["$field", null] }`

[image]